# .NET / .NET Core and SQL Server connection mismatch issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I am developing C# application which is executing ~30 sql queries every second... I have multiple threads which do that. My problem is that when I try to query the sql server with `SELECT ....` it returns different results.

Example:
If run both `SELECT * FROM Users` and `SELECT * FROM Jobs` at the same time from different threads i get responses like:

`SELECT * FROM Users` -> `Job colums with Job values`

`SELECT * FROM Jobs` -> `User colums with User values`

I am using Dapper like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_msSqlProvider.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return connection.Query<User>(
                    @"SELECT JobId 
                        FROM Users
                        WHERE Id = @userId
                        ORDER BY Id ASC",
                    new {userId});
            }
```

My application logs look like (i.e. the query is returning not User model data):

> An exception occured while getting user's job: A parameterless
>   default constructor or one matching signature (System.Int32 Id,
>   System.Int32 UserId, System.Decimal Salary, System.DateTime UpdatedAt)
>   is required for SampleApp.User materialization

My application is very different from this and complex but this should be good as example...

**Solution:**
If anyone reading this question is interested in what was the solution - enabling MARS and connection pooling resolved my issue...

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917836/connection-pool-one-process-many-threads

Comment: The exception in your application log isn't about wrong result sets from queries - it's about being able to instantiate the `new` anonymous type at runtime.

Comment: Instead of using JobId in your select query, check with  select * as you are trying to materialize with your User type though you are selecting JobId

Comment: Sounds like you are not thread safe.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - I am using only 2-3 connections at the same time

Comment: @ChrisWalsh - This was just an example with Users and Jobs tables, my application is much more complex... The models are perfectly fine - if I run the queries only from one thread it works just fine. The problem is that from this query, mssql (or the connection) returns the row from Jobs table instead of only JobId from Users table...

Comment: @Namphibian yeah, it looks so... but how I can be thread safe? I need to execute these queries at the same time(the application logic won't let me execute them in queue)

Comment: For thread safety globals needs to go out and you can use mutexes, semaphores, critical locks and so on to lock shared globals. Also you would need to make sure that the classes themselves are thread safe. Its a large topic.

Answer (score 0):

Must use different sql reader or sql command for right solution.
Try this;

```
        double vId;
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        if (db.OpenDR(ref dr, string.Format("select JobId from dbo.Users where Id={0}", vUSERID)))
        {
            if (dr.Read()) vId = dr["JobId"].dToDouble();
            dr.Close();
        }
        return vId;
```